# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {ELEMENT=1}

Tags: java, selenium, find, appium, element

Please solve my query

Hi write the  same code that you mention on your site for appium native app, but its gives error 
 main error is :-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {ELEMENT=1}
```

Please check the attachment for more clarification

My code :-

```
private static AndroidDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create object of DesiredCapabilities class                             
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        // Optional
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        // Specify the device name (any name)
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "My New Phone");
        // Platform version
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");
        // platform name
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        // specify the application package that we copied from appium                
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "io.selendroid.testapp");
        // specify the application activity that we copied from appium                   
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".HomeScreenActivity");
        // Start android driver I used 4727 port by default it will be 4723
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        // Specify the implicit wait of 5 second
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// Enter the text in textbox
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc='my_text_fieldCD']")).sendKeys("Mukesh Selenium Appium");
        // click on registration button  
        driver.findElement(By.id("io.selendroid.testapp:id/startUserRegistration")).click();

        // Wait for 10 second
Thread.sleep(5000L);

}}
```

***My error is :-***

```
Sep 14, 2017 3:36:41 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {ELEMENT=1}
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-92C398N', ip: '192.168.1.14', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:378)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:476)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByXPath(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:140)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByXPath(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByXPath(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:58)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at a1.Selendroid.main(Selendroid.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:376)
    ... 13 more
```

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Inderpreet kaur

Comment: downgraded the Appium client to:

Appium Java Client : java-client-5.0.0-BETA6

Comment: I am use the java client 5.0.3 version i think its latest version @zsbappa

Comment: Thank you its working fine now by using the  java-client-5.0.0-BETA6 Thank you alot @ZSbappa

Comment: Okay cool .... be in touch @ INDEPREETKAUR1993@GMAIL.COM

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231798/select-one-option-from-many-options-in-drop-down-list-in-eclipse-using-java-when                                            Hello zsbappa , can you please visit this URL and solve my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was the same problem

> Use the following version then
>   Appium : 1.6.5

Selenium : selenium-java-3.3.1

Appium Java Client : java-client-5.0.3

> I downgraded the Appium client to:

Appium Java Client : java-client-5.0.0-BETA6
and the problem was solved.