# Select one option from many options in drop down list in Eclipse using java when run code for the android device

Tags: javascript, java, android, eclipse, appium

**I want to select the one option from many options in dropdown menu in eclipse using java and run code for the android device.**

***code***

```
  public class Selendroid {
    private static AndroidDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create object of DesiredCapabilities class                             
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        // Optional
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        // Specify the device name (any name)
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "My New Phone");
        // Platform version
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");
        // platform name
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        // specify the application package that we copied from appium                
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.testingqw.laborfind");
        // specify the application activity that we copied from appium                   
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.testingqw.laborfind.Activity.SplashScreen");
        // Start android driver I used 4727 port by default it will be 4723
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        // Specify the implicit wait of 5 second
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.id("com.testingqw.laborfind:id/tv_default_spinner")).click();

          driver.findElement(By.name("English")).click();;
        // Wait for 10 second
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
```

Comment: Please share detail , what error you are getting.

Comment: THe method driver.scrollToExact("English"); is  undefined for the type  android driver @shiv

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("com.testingqw.laborfind:id/tv_default_spinner").click();
WebElement element=  driver.findElementByName("United States"); element.click(); If you can create xpath using name it will be good instead of finding by name

Comment: Can you please guide me how can i create xpath for name , i try but i cant  @shiv

Comment: driver.findElementByxpath('//UIATableCell[contains(@name,"English")]') , change UIATableCell as per element your app is  having.

Comment: selectLanuahe = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectLanuahe);
        List<String> categoriesgender = new ArrayList<String>();
        categoriesgender.add("Select Language");
        categoriesgender.add("English");
        categoriesgender.add("Arabic");
        categoriesgender.add("Hindi");
        categoriesgender.add("Bengali");
        categoriesgender.add("Malayalam");
        categoriesgender.add("Urdu");// categoriesgender.remove(0);                                                this is my xml , how can i find UIA   @shiv

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text() = 'English']")).click(); try this

Comment: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Not working      @zsbappa

Comment: again its not the java client issue , may be we use previous version @zsbappa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Hindi']")).click();***
***driver.findElement(By.xpath("//class[@text='specific text at that where you want to click ']")).click();***                                                                                        This is solution for the above query .its really work because i find this solution myself after alot R&D in two days.

Comment: yes, accept the answer by clicking tick icon , and its also work on latest version @shiv

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on spinner you can use driver.scrollToExact to navigate to particular field.K

driver.findElement(By.id("com.testingqw.laborfind:id/tv_default_spinner"));

driver.scrollToExact("English");

driver.findElement(By.name("English")).click();